# Android: Unable to zoom in/out webview for mobile site

Tags: android, webview

I cannot seem to get the Android webview to zoom in or out for mobile sites like:
    http://m.bbc.co.uk

The webpage just comes out in a single column.

I tried:

1. I have tried different permutations (true/false) with

   ```
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
   ```
2. I have also tried to

   ```
   WebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
   WebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   ```

but it is still not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried setBuiltInZoomControls

```
WebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: still not working for me. not sure how google got zooming to work for mobile sites in Chrome..